# How to point to ssh folder with private keys to automatically choose one?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I would like to be able to use

`ssh user@host`

without the `-i identity_rsa_or_else_private_key_file` . Is there a place somewhere in `ssh` configs where I can point where are the private keys located so that the `ssh` will automatically choose one for the connection (so that I don't have to type `-i key_file`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest reading the `ssh_config` man page.  If you want to have a specific identity per-host, and another for all other hosts, do something like this in your ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host hostname.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity_rsa_or_else_private_key_file

Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/another_identity_file
```

By default, it uses `~/.ssh/id_rsa` for the IdentityFile for RSA identities and `~/.ssh/id_dsa` for DSA identities, so if you don't want to change your ~/.ssh/config, you can just rename the file to that name.

Comment: Please note that `IdentityFile` only **adds** keys to what your key agent already offers to the SSH clients. If you have your key agent already N number of keys available, it will try to authenticate with N+1 keys, with the one you specified as the last one. Some SSH servers will have blocked you already by then. Check that with `ssh -vvv` and you might want to disable your SSH key agent by enabling `IdentitiesOnly`.